# keras "load_model" time increases when loading it multiple times

Tags: python, keras, execution-time

I have a python rest API(keras) which has 5 model files for 5 users. Following things happen when a request comes
1. check the user
2. load the relevant model for that specific user
3. execute it and output the result.

But my problem is when the request count increases, the time for the execution also increases.
[debug output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgqF9.jpg%5C)

code for the post request is as follows(flask app):

```
my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    model_name = "./"+userName+"/model.h5"
    scaler_name = "./"+userName+"/scaler.sc"
    modelPath = os.path.join(my_path, model_name)
    scalerPath = os.path.join(my_path, scaler_name)

    start_time = time.time()
    # load the model
    model = load_model(modelPath)
    scaler = joblib.load(scalerPath)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    ............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras isnt removing the models you are no longer using and is therefore still using memory.

You can try clear_session() as shown [here](https://keras.io/backend/), or if the models are the same, but with different weights, you can try to re-use your models but replace the weights.